What's this movie? can't find it anywhere
I'm looking for a movie about a couple who is expecting a baby & so is their neighbor but the couples' cat scares the other lady causing her to fall down the stairs and have miscarriage, so she blames her miscarriage on the other woman.

Movie year (any range), Movie format (B/W or colour), Possible movie language... We need more info...

We have quality standards regarding ID questions. Please add anything more you remember.  Any trivial detail will be helpful for the reopening the question.  Add the year you have watched, year of release if you remember, any scenes you remember, famous dialogues or punch lines. Use a better title.

The movie you're looking for is The Ones Below (2015).
From the Wikipedia entry for the film:

Kate (Clémence Poésy) and Justin (Stephen Campbell Moore) are expecting their first child. They also have new downstairs neighbors, Jon (David Morrissey) and Theresa (Laura Birn), who are also expecting their first baby. 

..

Eventually, Theresa, who has been sneaking wine all evening, says she doesn't feel well and gets up to leave. In her rush to get out the door, a tipsy Theresa trips over Kate’s cat and falls down the stairs and subsequently loses the baby, whom she was going to name Peter.

.. 

When Kate and Justin attempt to console the grieving couple, they end up in a fight with Theresa, who screams that Kate does not deserve "that thing" inside her.



This is my first movie identification answer. If I need to add more to it to meet site standards, please let me know. Thanks.

We appreciate that you are only trying to help but this question does not meet our quality standards. Providing answers to such low quality questions only encourages equally low quality questions. You might wish to consider removing this answer in the interests of the site.

IMO i've always thought this site's "quality standards" are too stringent. People come here for answers and in all honesty if they could remember enough to meet your "quality standards" then they most likely would be able to find the answer themselves.  And now you ask people to not answer questions even if they know the answer to support these stringent standards.  What is the purpose of this board supposed to be then?  I suggest questions get deleted after a certain period of time if unanswered instead of the forum police continuing to alienate people from coming here.  Just my two cents
